# Use area of intersection as a variable in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, st-intersects

I have two geojson files - `NYCSample` and `censusTracts`.  Each census tract contains a population attribute (integer).  My objective is to multiply the population attribute by the % area of intersection / total area of tract that `NYCSample` intersects.  For example, we see that the sample layer intersects 6 census tracts.  If each of the census tracts contain 100 people, then the output should be 100 * (% of intersection).

Using the `st_area(st_intersection())` functions in PostGIS, how would one output a table with population adjusted for % of area intersected?

So far, I've written this query but am not sure how to create a separate `pop_adjusted` variable

```
CREATE TABLE test_join
AS
  SELECT t.*, m.*
  FROM censusTracts AS t , NYCSample AS m
  WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, m.geom)
  AND (
    ST_Area(ST_Intersection(t.geom, m.geom))
    /ST_Area(t.geom)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: you need to add the (st_area(st_intersection(t.geom, m.geom))/st_area(t.geom)) up in the select part of the query

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing some stuff. You want all rows in which there is an intersection carried over. That means that *only* the call to `ST_Intersects` should be in the join-condition or where-clause.

I've modified the table to use explicit joins.

```
CREATE TABLE test_join
AS
  SELECT
    ST_Area(ST_Intersection(t.geom, m.geom)) / ST_Area(t.geom) * pop AS pop_adjusted
    t.*,
    m.*, 
  FROM censusTracts AS t
  JOIN NYCSample AS m
    ON ST_Intersects(t.geom, m.geom)
```

It's also somewhat worth nothing that this needn't be a seperate table. You can create a view (see [`CREATE VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html)) just the same way, and qgis should be able to display it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `ST_Area` in the `WHERE` clause is overcomplicated, it will evaluate to false only if the result of the division is zero `st_area(st_intersection(t.geom, m.geom)) >0` would suffice. Also explicit join might be better

```
SELECT t.*
       ,m.population * SUM(st_area(st_intersection(t.geom, m.geom))/st_area(t.geom)) as pod_adjusted
FROM censusTracts AS t 
  JOIN NYCSample AS m
    ON st_intersects(t.geom, m.geom)
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: I don't understand what this clause `>0` is supposed to do with ST_Intersection(t.geom,m.geom) > 0`

Comment: I'm still not sure what that does. You're just writing another slower version of `ST_Intersects` that you already have.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Well, I just simplified the original query. TBH I haven't used postgis in a bit and I'm not really sure if intersection always has an area greater than zero

Comment: you're right to say that. `ST_Intersects` will return true if they `ST_Touches`. Though I would write that as `not ST_Touches()`  or something more explicit.

Comment: @EvanCarroll You may be right about the explicity, though `ST_Touches` requires another function call while this only reuses what's already there. Though with Sum() it doesn't really matter...I'll guess I'll remove it.